# How to make Emulator like Ainol legend 7 4.0.2?

Tags: android

I want make emulator like ainol legend 7 4.0.2 for testing my application.
My application is running in all the device but in the ainol legend 7 4.0.2 device can not run properly.

How can I fix that?

Comment: can you post that device specification?

Comment: 7 inch tablet capacitive screen
 
Ainol Novo 7 Legend
 
Android 4.0.4

Comment: is it mdpi or hdpi device? create emulator with 800 x600 res and test it? what the problem you are facing to create emulator.

Comment: in ainol there are not open the menu option.

Comment: sorry? is your api level > 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  create an AVD for the emulator, with the exact measurements as the Novo 7" tablet.
The log lines in my java code show the same values as for the real tablet device:

> Ainol Novo 7" tablet **Emulator**:  ScaledDensity: 1.0, Density DPI: 160, **width in dp: 800, height in dp: 480**

However, on the emulator, you can place a view with **580dp** x 320 dp to to fully visible in a fullscreen activity.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.